# How to define array in Groovy soapUI?

Tags: arrays, groovy, soapui

I am working in soapUI. I need to define Array in Groovy in soapUI groovy script.

Could you please help me

Comment: Please provide your example code here. This makes it easier.

Comment: Do you mean a Groovy Array, or a soap-enc:array ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// Define the array
def MAX_SIZE = 4
def myArray = new Object[MAX_SIZE]

// Fill the array
myArray[0] = "This"
myArray[1] = "is"
myArray[2] = "my"
myArray[3] = "array."

// Print content of the array
myArray.each { log.info(it) }
```

Comment: Very nice and short way of printing an array

Answer (score 0):

See here, for example: http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN1025-Arrays

Comment: But the following statement is giving errors by defining array, Pls help - def a= new Object[4]

Comment: What is the error message? Have a look at the soapUI error log