# Trying to write a groovy script to build dynamic variables to run test cases in SoapUI

Tags: groovy, soapui

we already have groovy runner script that works and I am trying modify it to make it easier for to team to select and deselect environment and tests to run.

all possible tests and environments have their own custom property in the test case hosting the groovy script.
If the custom property is set to 0 the test wont run. if it is anything else that 0, the test will run.

My script builds 2 variable by looking at every environment and test custom property and it works fine until the rest of the script reads the variables the first part of the script built.

Here is one of the variable builder scripts.

```
runEnv =  "["
// Env. 7031
    if (testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue( 'Env-7031' ) == '1')
        {runEnv = runEnv + "'7031'"}
// Env. 7131
    if (testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue( 'Env-7031' ) == '1')
        // runs if a comma is needed to separate values
        {if (testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue( 'Env-7131' ) == '1')
            {runEnv = runEnv + ",'7131'"}}
    else
        // runs if value is the first in line and doesnt need comma
        {if (testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue( 'Env-7131' ) == '1')
            {runEnv = runEnv + "'7131'"}}
// Adding the end of runEnv
runEnv = runEnv + "]"
// Verification message confirming what environment(s) will be tested
log.info 'Environment Selection is: ' + runEnv

runEnvironment = runEnv
```

The expected result of this script is that runEnvironmet's value would be ['7031'] if the custom property of env-7031 is set to 1 and env-7131 set to 0

When I run this script, I get this log:

```
Wed May 06 07:09:38 EDT 2020:INFO:Environment Selection is: ['7031']
Wed May 06 07:09:38 EDT 2020:INFO:Test Case Selection is: ['Build-Deploy - All Tables']
Wed May 06 07:09:38 EDT 2020:INFO:Release Artifact Runner
Wed May 06 07:09:38 EDT 2020:INFO:Start Test Runner
Wed May 06 07:09:38 EDT 2020:INFO:Environment: [
```

we can see that the Environment is not looking as it should. [ instead of ['7031']

Is it possible to use groovy to build a variable in that manner?

TL:DR

trying to get a hardcoded variable

```
runEnvironment = ['7031']
```

from a script that use custom properties to build that variable from scratch.
like this simulation

```
runEnvironment = '[' + "'7031'" + ']'
```

Comment: I don't see the `runEnvironment` declaration and usage in your code. but it seems it's used as an array. so the syntax `runEnvironment = ['7031']` is correct.

Comment: my problem was that i wasn't building an array, I was building a text string.
Building it as an array, I didnt need to add the [ ] and the extra " ".

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968028/how-to-define-array-in-groovy-soapui Helped me a lot about how to build my array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I was building a text string.
The script needs an array to go through.

This is how I learned to created my array. [How to define array in Groovy soapUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968028/how-to-define-array-in-groovy-soapui)

This is the script I ended with:

```
def maxEnv = 0  
// defining how many environments the array will include
    // Env. 7031
        if (testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue( 'Env-7031' ) == '0'){}else{
            testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue( 'Env-7031', '1' ) 
            maxEnv = maxEnv + 1 }
    // Env. 7131
        if (testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue( 'Env-7131' ) == '0'){}else{
            testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue( 'Env-7131', '1' ) 
            maxEnv = maxEnv + 1 }

log.info maxEnv ("Environments")

// Building runEnv array
def runEnv = new Object[maxEnv]
curEnv = 99

    // Env. 7031
        if (testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue( 'Env-7031' ) == '1')
            {if (curEnv == 99){curEnv = 0}else{curEnv = curEnv + 1)
            runEnv[curEnv] = '7031'} else {}
    // Env. 7131
        if (testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue( 'Env-7131' ) == '1')
            {if (curEnv == 99){curEnv = 0}else{curEnv = curEnv + 1)
            runEnv[curEnv] = '7131'} else {}

runEnvironment = runEnv
```